# Accessing class method in objective c. Using self or classname?

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, class-method

I am learning iOS programming and am confused by the following code regarding the use of keyword self.

From my understanding, `self` is like Java's `this`. It refers to the current instance. When I want to call a class method, the usual way should be like  `[PlayingCard validSuits];` But it's also OK to invade a class method on an instance, right? Like `[self validSuits];` (I am in the class so self refers to an instance of PlayingCard)

But in the following code, it gives error somewhere but looks ok elsewhere.(Pointed out by 3 comments, this is within Xcode 5.1)

Am I missing anything?

(P.S. I think I am having the similar problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660042/no-known-class-method-for-selector-validsuits-error-in-xcode-5-1), which no one answered yet. He got the same error even using [PlayingCard validSuits]. )

```
//  PlayingCard.m

#import "PlayingCard.h"

@implementation PlayingCard
@synthesize suit = _suit; 

+ (NSArray *)validSuits {
    return @[@"♠︎", @"♣︎", @"♥︎", @"♦︎"];
}

+ (NSArray *)rankStrings {
    return @[@"?", @"A", @"2", @"3", @"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K"];

}

+ (NSUInteger)maxRank {
    return [[PlayingCard rankStrings] count] -1; 
          //1. [self rankStrings] works fine.** 
}


//override super class's method
- (NSString *)contents {

    NSArray *rankStrings = [PlayingCard rankStrings];  
           //2. if change rankStrings to self, then error:
           //No visible @interface for 'PlayingCard' declares the selector 'rankStrings'

    return [rankStrings[self.rank] stringByAppendingString:self.suit];
}

- (void) setSuit:(NSString *)suit {
    if ( [[PlayingCard validSuits] containsObject:suit]) {  
        //3.error when changed to [self validsuits] 
        //No visible @interface for 'PlayingCard' declares the selector 'validsuits'**
       _suit = suit;
    }

}

- (NSString *) suit {
    return _suit ? _suit : @"?";
}

@end
```

The header file:

```
//  PlayingCard.h

#import "Card.h"

@interface PlayingCard : Card

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *suit;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger rank;

+ (NSArray *) validSuits;
+ (NSUInteger) maxRank;

@end
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are calling another class method from inside a class method (of the same class) you can just use `[self classMethod]`. If however you are in an instance method and you need to call that classes class method you can use `[[self class] classMethod]`

As pointed out by [@Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) - if you subclass `PlayingCard`, calling `self` in a class method will then be that subclass and not `PlayingCard`.

EDIT:

For completeness you need to do:

```
//  PlayingCard.m

#import "PlayingCard.h"

@implementation PlayingCard
@synthesize suit = _suit; 

+ (NSArray *)validSuits {
    return @[@"♠︎", @"♣︎", @"♥︎", @"♦︎"];
}

+ (NSArray *)rankStrings {
    return @[@"?", @"A", @"2", @"3", @"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K"];

}

+ (NSUInteger)maxRank {
    return [[self rankStrings] count] -1; 
}

//override super class's method
- (NSString *)contents {

    NSArray *rankStrings = [[self class] rankStrings];  

    return [rankStrings[self.rank] stringByAppendingString:self.suit];
}

- (void) setSuit:(NSString *)suit {
    if ( [[[self class] validSuits] containsObject:suit]) {  
       _suit = suit;
    }
}

- (NSString *) suit {
    return _suit ? _suit : @"?";
}

@end
```

Comment: Just note that using `[self class]` instead of `ClassName` does make a difference if `self` is an instance of a *subclass*.

Comment: Yes, I'll update the answer to clarify that - I think for this case it won't matter but it would be good to give a full answer.

Comment: That's it! So I am understanding it this way. You always invoke class methods on a class. Inside the class method, self refers to the class. Inside an instance method, self refers to the instance so you need [self class]. Also, I am thinking of Java's example like: aMathObject.sqrt(5); Are their underlying mechanism the same? any insights?

Comment: Yep! While `self` in an instance method is the same as `this` in Java, I don't think there's an equivalent in Java for `self` in a class method as when calling a `static` method in Java you need to explicitly qualify the class of the method - `JavaClass.staticMethodName()`

Comment: @MartinR   Let's say, PlayingCard inherits Card. Then, `[self class]` refers to the same thing as using `PlayingCard`. Am I right?

Comment: @WeishiZeng: If self is an instance of PlayingCard then [self class] is PlayingCard, even when called inside a method of the parent class Card.

Comment: @MartinR you mean the method of parent class Card, but overridden in subclass PlayingCard, right? (in this case, - (NSString *)contents) Otherwise, I can't think of an example self stays in subclass but called inside superclass method.